# How to print only odd page/even page with CRRuntime_32bit_13_0_4 and Crystal report 10

Tags: printing, crystal-reports

I'm using the CanonLPB2900 printer, which is not a duplex printer so it can not flip the paper on it’s own.
So I want to print all the odd pages first, then print all the even pages later.

I've tried everything I could found. Formula, New page after, New page before, replace the even page with blank page then skip the blank page... but it still print all the pages

My report will be like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TTQpk.png)

May I ask how to setup to print all the odd pages first, then print all the even pages later?

Comment: This question is not about programming, so this is the wrong place to ask. Maybe you can ask this in another site of the Stack Exchange network. You can find the sites here: https://stackexchange.com/sites

Comment: Your printer's driver may already provide an easy way to do this.  If you open the printer properties for this printer, there should be some options to setup Manual Duplex printing.  Then when you want to print double-sided it knows to print the odd pages and then waits for you to flip over the output pages so they can feed through again to print the even pages.  Some print drivers also provide a setting for "Pages" when printing that will allow you to choose to print only the odd or even numbered pages.